# Небольшая проблема с общей папкой в Ubuntu под VirtualBox на Windows 7 (и еще 2 вопроса)

Tags: windows, virtualbox, ubuntu

Поставил Ubuntu 10.4 на Windows 7 под VirtualBox 4.1.6 с пользователем avp.

Начал настраивать передачу данных через общую папку. В меню виртуальной машины назвал ее sharedir (в Windows c:\sharedir).В Ubuntu образовалось оглавление

```
drwxrwx--- root vxboxsf /media/sf_sheredir
```

chmod 777 на него отрабатывает нормально, но права не меняются (но если вдуматься, то объяснимо).

***Собственно вопрос:  как лучше организовать обмен данными ?***

Понятно, из под root все хорошо, но по умолчанию все из интерфейса стартует от avp. В общем немного неудобно.

Я решил дописать avp к группе vxboxsf и спросить у знатоков администрирования, **как правильно** Вы это организуете. Понятно, что в моем случае (один юзер, он же админ), как ни сделай, все сойдет, а как надо делать в многопользовательской среде ?

Сходу задам еще пару вопросов:

2) *Как увеличить таймаут на блокирование экрана и запрос пароля у avp ?* Среда GNOME 2.30.2

3) *Как организовать Copy/Paste между окошками GNOME и Windows* ? Подозреваю, что это в настройках VirtualBox, но сходу ничего не нашел.

Заранее благодарен.

**UPD**

Вопросы 2) и 3) отпали.

2) В меню GNOME "Система" -> "Параметры" -> "Хранитель экрана"

3) Все заработало (?). Видимо "не на те клавиши нажимал", а может перезагрузка Windows после установки VirtualBox и Ubuntu повлияла. Но вопрос отпал.

Comment: Правильнее ставить Виндоус на виртуалку (VirtualBox, VMWare, Xen) Линукса (безопасность, производительность...).

Comment: А у меня так и не заработало (ни 1 ни 2). Там есть ряд галок в свойствах виртуальной машины, позволяющих пользоваться копи-пэйстом, но даже после установки набора расширений, так ничего и не получилось.

Answer (score 1):

Права на папку стоит менять не в Ubuntu, а напротив, в Windows. Проверьте разрешения NTFS.